# Is DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE intent broadcasted system wise?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to know if every app registered for `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` can receive the intent or only the app that initiates the download gets this intent.

I am trying to receive this intent in my app when chrome downloads a file, but it looks like this intent is not even being broadcasted.

My app work reacts if I send the same intent via adb command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you acquire instance of `DownloadManger` through your **application** `context` the download complete `intent` going to be package **private**. It means only the application that requested download can receive the broadcast related to it.